# What is {...code...} in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
{
var x = 0;
...
}
```

What are the curly  braces supposed to do, it is clearly not a function or a loop, it's just empty curly braces with nothing before.

p.s. if anyone finds a better way to rephrase this question, please do

Comment: It's a [*BlockStatement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-BlockStatement). In that context, it's meaningless.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: In ES6 they can be used to define a block scope for `let` and `const` declarations.

Answer (score 4):

Those are called block statements, they are simply there to group together statements to be executed together.

Here are some useful links:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. MDN is fine.